# How to check if all data entries in a table is in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, database

I have table full of data that I want to match up with a table from Oracle SQL Database. The table I have does not have all of the columns in the Database and has a smaller set of data. I just want a fairly simple way to check if the data can be matched up with a row in the Database.

Comment: I removed the incompatible software tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I honestly have not clue what to do. I am fairly new to this. First I filtered out some of the stuff I know isn't in the table, so they both have around 300,000 rows of data. I don't know where to go from here besides sorting the rows and matching them up.